# How to remove "all new line character" in a JAVA string

Tags: java

I just want to remove everything after a new line in a JAVA string.
For Example:-
If String = "Class
             Name
             Address"

I want my output to be = "Class"

***It is not a String Array it is one String with 3 lines***

Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Post the `String` and your attempts, please...

Comment: Split the string over newline, as described in the linked duplicate at the top of this page, and take the first element of the resulting array.

Comment: Depending on OS end of line is a combination of `\n` and/or `\r`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```java
public class Main {

  public static String firstLine(String s){
    if (s == null) return null;
    int cr = s.indexOf("\r");
    int nl = s.indexOf("\n");
    if (cr == -1 && nl == -1) return s;
    if (cr >= 0 && nl >= 0) return s.substring(0, Math.min(cr, nl));
    if (cr >= 0) return s.substring(0, cr);
    return s.substring(0, nl);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(firstLine("line one"));
    System.out.println(firstLine("line one\r\nline two"));
    System.out.println(firstLine("line one\nline two"));
    System.out.println(firstLine("line one\r\nline two\r\nline three"));
    System.out.println(firstLine("line one\nline two\nline three"));
  }

}
```

Output is always: `line one`

Comment: Or a one line solution: `return s.split("\\r?\\n")[0];`